# Any unique quantum phenomena for $N>3$ levels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

**Context**

I am asking this question in the context of atomic physics and coherently driven few-level systems. So, for concreteness, one particle ($n=1$) which has $N$ states available. Because $n=1$, behavior arising from being a Boson or Fermion is out-of-scope of this question (although they contain lots of interesting physics).

**Motivation for question**

To understand few level dynamics, one usually begins with a two level system. There, a coherent drive  (e.g. a laser) can induce Rabi flopping between the two states when near resonance. I'm addition, you can get Autler-Townes splitting (or AC Stark shifts) of the levels as they get dressed by the drive. All of these effects were observed many decades ago and are well-understood.

Then one moves on to three level systems (lambda, vee, ladder) and a rich set of new phenomena show up: stimulated Raman transitions, coherent population trapping, electromagnetically induced transparency (EIT), and rapid adiabatic passage (STIRAP). These effects are non-intuitive and dramatic. For example, light traveling through a medium exhibiting EIT can slow down to be slower than a [bicycle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetically_induced_transparency#Slow_light_and_stopped_light)!

Surprisingly (to me), most of these phenomena were discovered relatively recently, with EIT and STIRAP being theoretically described and experimentally observed in the 80s and 90s. That is despite the fact that all the tools were present well before that.

**The Question**

**Are there similar *genuinely new* phenomena that show up when you driving four-level atomic systems, or other $N>3$ systems, where $N$ is still a relatively small number?** Presumably these systems are small enough that one can "brute force" map out the density matrix evolution quite easily.

I have seen things like "double EIT" in the literature for four+level systems, but at face value that seems like a very trivial extension of $N=3$.

Comment: Just how few are we talking? 6 fermionic modes/spins is under 100 states and you can probably start to see the onset of certain many-body effects in systems that size

Comment: @BySymmetry thanks, this is a soft question, I am aware of that and its pitfalls. I'm mostly interested in atomic levels (ie spin states, orbitals) where the number of fermions $n$ is fixed (mainly $n=1$ really) but the number of states available changes. Fermion statistics makes scaling $n$ a whole different topic that is orthogonal to the context I have in mind. I've edited accordingly

Comment: I'm mostly surprised that atomic physics textbooks stop at 3 level systems. I understand the math is messy and particular for $N>3$, but I'd expect at least a few unexpected and dramatic phenomena like when going from $N=2$ to $N=3$. Hope that clarified my context

Comment: Not sure if it fits your question, but there are [four-level lasers](https://www.rp-photonics.com/four_level_and_three_level_laser_gain_media.html), which can reach population inversion even with a small intensity of pumping, drastically reducing the lasing threshold compared to a three-level medium.

Comment: Proposals for scalable generation of photonic entanglement [typically uses](https://journals.aps.org/prx/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevX.7.041023) systems with more than four levels. [Chiral effects](https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.105.023712) are also usually generated in systems with [four or more](file:///Users/strom001/Downloads/ncomms6713.pdf) [levels](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-22597-z.pdf), but there may be counterexamples.

Answer (score 0):

In fact yes there are new quantum phenomena that apparently only occur for $N>3$, although not in atomic but in (closely related) interferometers.

In a [recent paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41566-023-01213-0):

> Seron, B., Novo, L. and Cerf, N.J., 2023. Boson bunching is not maximized by indistinguishable particles. Nature Photonics, pp.1-8.

the authors show that boson bunching can be "boosted" in optical interferometers.  Quoting from the abstract:
"This boosting effect is already visible in a seven-photon interferometric process".  It's not clear if boosting can occur with fewer than 7 photons, but the boosting cannot occur for $N=2$ photons and the $N=3$ case is sufficiently simple so that, if overbunching existed in such systems, it would have been discovered already.

This group has another related recent result [available on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.12226).

Comment: Thanks, though this doesn't fit with the context I mentioned in the question. I'm trying to understand the dynamics of a single particle which can occupy multiple states without the extra behavior that comes along with being a Boson or Fermion. I'm just surprised that there aren't as amazing things as STIRAP and EIT in higher N systems.

Comment: yes I realize it’s not a perfect fit.